# Fetching data of <T> from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm using the Node version of Firestore (I'm used to the Angular version) and having some trouble with the syntax.

I have a firebase table which stores a uniform set of objects, all complying with a typescript interface called "ArchiveRecord", stored in a collection called `BKArchive`.

I can get these records back by id as a generic `DocumentData`, but I would like to retrieve them as `ArchiveRecords`.

It seemed like something like:

```js
let fs = getFirestore(app)
let myDoc = await getDoc<ArchiveRecord>(fs, 'BKArchive', docId)
```

It seems like it ought to work, but I'm getting a strange compile error on the `fs` parameter to `getDoc()` (fs is supposed to be a Firestore instance).  The error message is `Argument of type 'Firestore' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CollectionReference<ArchiveRecord>'.`

The message doesn't make any sense to me, it supposed to be a Firestore instance, according to the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The Error you received means `getDoc()` expects a `DocumentReference` or `QueryDocumentSnapshot` take a look at this [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)

You can receive data returned from `getDoc()` as a type of `ArchiveRecord` as follows:

```js
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getFirestore, doc, getDoc } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { ArchiveRecord } from './ArchiveRecord'; // import for ArchiveRecord
const firebaseConfig = {
   // …
};
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const firestore = getFirestore(app); //firestore initialized 
const docRef = doc(firestore, 'BKArchive', docId);
const snapshot = await getDoc(docRef);
// Bellow is your record with all type safety assuming all
// document data is of the same type.
const myRecord = snapshot.data() as ArchiveRecord;
```

Basically, we are casting the data received from Firestore to your `ArchiveRecord` interface using the `as` keyword.
You might think well this should also might work : `const snapshot = await getDoc<ArchiveRecord>(docRef);` but it will not because `snapshot` will not be cast into `ArchiveRecord` but `snapshot.data()` can be cast into `ArchiveRecord`;